# How to inject a service outside component declaration

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, ngx-translate

I'm working on an **Angular 7** project and I'm using the **ngx-translate** library for localization and internationalization. I'm facing a problem when injecting providers dynamically.

I have a simple form component, which includes a date picker. I'm using the **ng-bootstrap** library for Bootstrap 4 components. The Datepicker component allows us to inject calendar and i18n providers to localize the picker. For example:

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: NgbCalendar, useClass: NgbCalendarPersian },
    { provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useClass: NgbDatepickerI18nPersian } 
  ]
  ...
})
```

Now the problem is, I want to provide these classes **ONLY** if the current language is **fa** (Farsi). I tried using factories, that didn't help. For instance:

```
export function NgbCalendarFactory(translate: TranslateService) {
  let lang = translate.currentLang;
  if (lang == 'fa')
    return new NgbCalendarPersian();
  else
    return new NgbCalendarGregorian();
}

export function NgbDatepickerFactory(translate: TranslateService) {
  let lang = translate.currentLang;
  if (lang == 'fa')
    return new NgbDatepickerI18nPersian();
  else
    return new NgbDatePickerI18nDefault();
}

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: NgbCalendar, useFactory: NgbCalendarFactory, deps: [TranslateService] },
    { provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useFactory: NgbDatepickerFactory, deps: [TranslateService] }
  ]
  ...
})
```

Factories seem to be the way to go, but the default classes cannot be resolved. The **NgbDatePickerI18nDefault** and **NgbCalendarGregorian** classes throw compile-time errors, and they have been imported correctly too. No idea.

I've been struggling with this for hours. One way to solve the issue is, check the current language, and only if applicable, provide those instances. Something likes this:

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: currentLang == 'fa' ? [
    { provide: NgbCalendar, useFactory: NgbCalendarFactory, deps: [TranslateService] },
    { provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useFactory: NgbDatepickerFactory, deps: [TranslateService] }
  ] : []
  ...
})
```

So if the current language is **en** for example, I'll leave the providers array empty for this component. Now how can I inject the **TranslateService** in my typescript file, outside of the component declaration? Obviously, I can't inject it in the class constructor, or manually using the Injector or ReflectiveInjector services, because I need to check the language at the time of component declaration.

I'm fairly new to Angular 7, so perhaps I'm thinking about this all wrong.

Comment: I have resolved the issue for now, but I'd very much like to understand this use case better. What I've done is, I created a component that wraps the Persian calendar. And in my form component, I display different date picker inputs based on the current language. Works fine, but I need to understand what is the answer to my original questions.